# 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'fn' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, multi-select

I am trying to do this example http://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/w7aakdbb/54/

There I am getting this exception

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'fn' of undefined or null reference.
and 
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'multiselect' .
It is throwing error at this point in bootstarp-multiselect.js

```
$.fn.multiselect = function(option, parameter, extraOptions) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var data = $(this).data('multiselect');
        var options = typeof option === 'object' && option;

        // Initialize the multiselect.
        if (!data) {
            data = new Multiselect(this, options);
            $(this).data('multiselect', data);
        }

        // Call multiselect method.
        if (typeof option === 'string') {
            data[option](parameter, extraOptions);

            if (option === 'destroy') {
                $(this).data('multiselect', false);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

My HTML code:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<select id="ddlCars" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="Accord">Accord</option>
   <option value="Duster">Duster</option>
   <option value="Esteem">Esteem</option>
   <option value="Fiero">Fiero</option>
</select>
<script>
   $('#ddlCars').multiselect();
</script>
```

I am using ASP.NET MVC project in VS2013.
There I am getting this exception 
I am very new to JS and BootStarp.

Comment: `jquery.js` needs to be first (before `bootstrap-multiselect.js)`

Comment: Thanks. It helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Correct the order of scripts*, jQuery js should be the first to load because `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap-multiselect.js` depends on `jquery js`.

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved my first problem. Now I am getting error that 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'multiselect'.

Comment: @JyotirmayaPrusty..if possible create a fiddle describing your problem so that it will be easy for us to debug and correct the code.

Comment: This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/iminfo/txnot4h1/ I am working on. Works fine in the fiddle, but I am getting this error in VS13

Answer (score 1):

What the error says is that `$` is not yet defined (during execution of bootstarp-multiselect.js), because you need to load jQuery first.

And since `bootstrap-multiselect.js` can depend on bootstrap, it doesn't harm to also load `bootstrap.js` before `bootstrap-multiselect.js`.

So:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
...
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved my first problem. Now I am getting error that 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'multiselect'.

Comment: Try to execute your code on document ready instead of directly: `$(function() { $('#ddlCars').multiselect(); });`, see https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I am doing this fiddle now : http://jsfiddle.net/iminfo/txnot4h1/
This works fine in Fiddle but throwing above error in VS13.

Answer (score 0):

order of javascript file inclusion is wrong, jQuery file should be included first.